# jQuery multiple selectors as variables

Tags: jquery

I need help with jQuery's multiple selectors. I understand how it works and have used it but I need to use it in a way that the element names aren't in the function. (They're being passed as variables due to them being dynamically created)

Here's an example of what I have:

```
function openBox(row) {
    var rowInfo = '#info' + row;
    var rowClose = '#close' + row;
    var rowNumber = '#number' + row;
    $(rowInfo).slideDown('slow');
    $(rowClose).slideDown('slow');
    $(rowNumber).slideDown('slow');
}
```

While this is fine and works, I was hoping to clean it up a bit and find use of jQuery's multiple selectors (or something of the kind) but I noticed when passing variables this way, it doesn't seem to work but doesn't throw any errors as to why.

Example of what I want:

```
function openBox(row) {
    var rowInfo = '#info' + row;
    var rowClose = '#close' + row;
    var rowNumber = '#number' + row;
    $(rowInfo, rowClose, rowNumber).slideDown('slow');
}
```

Is this possible? Unfortunately their documentation doesn't go into great length about passing anything other than html elements. [source](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a group of selectors:

```
function openBox(row) {
    var rowInfo = '#info' + row;
    var rowClose = '#close' + row;
    var rowNumber = '#number' + row;
    $(rowInfo + ", " + rowClose + ", " + rowNumber).slideDown('slow');
}
```

or the `add` method:

```
function openBox(row) {
    var rowInfo = '#info' + row;
    var rowClose = '#close' + row;
    var rowNumber = '#number' + row;
    $(rowInfo)
        .add(rowClose)
        .add(rowNumber)
        .slideDown('slow');
}
```

---

Both can be more concise, of course:

```
function openBox(row) {
    $('#info' + row + ", #close" + row + ", #number" + row).slideDown('slow');
}
```

or the `add` method:

```
function openBox(row) {
    $('#info' + row)
        .add('#close' + row)
        .add('#number' + row)
        .slideDown('slow');
}
```

---

But perhaps it would make sense to give all of these elements a common class based on the `row`?

```
<div id="infoX" class="rowX">...</div>
<div id="closeX" class="rowX">...</div>
<div id="numberX" class="rowX">...</div>
```

Then it would be:

```
function openBox(row) {
    $(".row" + row).slideDown("slow");
}
```

Comment: That's awesome. And thank you for the extra length you went to for multiple choice answers.

Answer (score 5):

You can concatenate strings to create a selector string;

```
var selector = [rowInfo, rowClose, rowNumber].join(',');
$(selector).slideDown('slow');
```

Or, You can use [`.add()`](https://api.jquery.com/add/) to group then in a jQuery object

```
 $(rowInfo).add(rowClose).add(rowNumber).slideDown('slow');
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also avoid the multiple variable and use an array, which you modify with map and then join with `,` to create the multiple selectors string for jQuery. So if you need to add more `id`s in the list you just add them to a single place

```
function openBox(row) {
    var targets = ['#info', '#close', '#number'].map(v=>v+row).join(',');
    $(targets).slideDown('slow');
}
```